# ra3290 on hp 250 does not work

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hp, wifi-hardware-switch

rfkill says phy0 is hard blocked (by a non existing HW switch).

With fn+F12 I am able to toggle soft blocked.

Installing rt3290 with dkms did not help, the "lid trick" does not work, installing linux-firmware-nonfree did not change anything.

Reset BIOS to Default did not help either, only brought the USB timeouts back.
 Any Idea anyone ? The Laptop is dualboot with win 10 pro via rEFInd (WiFi works in win).
Output from wireless-info: [rt2800](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11106928/) [rt3290sta](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11107340/)

I have found a workaround now: Booting with acpi=off made the HW block disappear (acpi=ht, noapic, nolapic, pnpacpi=off did not do it. When I tried pci=noapci, I had no /root).

Solution: BIOS update.